# When I click on the save button it will check that data on the database before saving it in Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

When I click on the save button it will check that data on the database before saving it in Django. search data at database before insert in Django administration. I don't want to save the same data that already save in the database.

like this on:
Here Home save to double. But I want that if the home already saves then the second time I try to Save the same name it will not save.
How can I code it?

models.py

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_id = models.id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    brand_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
```

[image]

Comment: add `unique=True` to `brand_name`. also you dont need to ad brand_id, every object in your db will have an auto ID field

Comment: Thanks, @hansTheFranz I am new to python. So I am still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Miss to Add `unique=True` to `brand_name`.

```
brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add `unique=True` to avoid duplicates:

```
brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

Comment: I am new to python. So I am still learning. Thanks @C14L

Answer (score 1):

Use `unique=True` if you want a unique field.

As you are new to python, the following tricks can come handy in future

Suppose you want a combination of fields to be unique you could add Constraints in Meta

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, index=True)
    brand_location = models.CharField(max_length=255, index=True)
    brand_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['brand_name', 'brand_location'], name='unique_brand')
        ]
```

*Now you will have only a unique brand_name per location.*

You can read more on constraints from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/)